Is there any trick to ensure the last selected value of scrollview to center with animation
I worked a lot in my scrollView. Everything is write but with a problem. I want that when the user stops scrolling, then the last selected value comes into the center of scrollview and the selected value not remains in. the outside of the center.
//
//  TextView.swift
//  Blood Pressure Tracker
//
//  Created by MacBook on 27/09/2024.
//

import SwiftUI

struct HorizontalPicker<T: Hashable & CustomStringConvertible>: View {
    @Binding var selectedValue: T // Binding for the selected value
    let values: [T]               // The array of values to display
    let itemWidth: CGFloat = 80   // Width of each item

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
            // Picker label
            VStack {
                Text("Select Value")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)

                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 60)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)

                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                // Add padding to ensure centering for the first and last elements
                                Spacer()
                                    .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - (itemWidth / 2))
                                
                                ForEach(values, id: \.self) { value in
                                    Text("\(value.description)")
                                        .font(.title2)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .padding()
                                        .foregroundColor(selectedValue == value ? .white : .black)
                                        .background(
                                            Circle()
                                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                                .foregroundColor(selectedValue == value ? .blue : .clear)
                                        )
                                        .background(GeometryReader { geo in
                                            Color.clear
                                                .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .global).midX) { midX in
                                                    // Calculate screen's center
                                                    let screenCenterX = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
                                                    let distance = abs(midX - screenCenterX)
                                                    let tolerance: CGFloat = 20 // Adjust tolerance as needed
                                                    if distance < tolerance {
                                                        selectedValue = value
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        })
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            // Scroll to the tapped value and select it
                                            withAnimation {
                                                selectedValue = value
                                                scrollView.scrollTo(value, anchor: .center)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .id(value) // Assign id for ScrollViewReader
                                }
                                
                                Spacer()
                                    .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - (itemWidth / 2))
                            }
                            .onAppear {
                                // Scroll to the initially selected value when the view appears
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    scrollView.scrollTo(selectedValue, anchor: .center)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 100) // Constrain the height of the ScrollView
                }
            }

            Spacer()
            
            // Show selected value
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Selected Value: \(selectedValue.description)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

// Preview
struct HorizontalPickerPreview: View {
    @State private var selectedInt = 110
    @State private var selectedString = "Apple"
    @State private var selectedFloat: Float = 5.5

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            // Integer picker
            HorizontalPicker(selectedValue: $selectedInt, values: Array(80...200))
                .frame(height: 150)

            // String picker
            HorizontalPicker(selectedValue: $selectedString, values: ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Elderberry"])
                .frame(height: 150)
            
            // Float picker
            HorizontalPicker(selectedValue: $selectedFloat, values: stride(from: 1.0, through: 10.0, by: 0.5).map { Float($0) })
                .frame(height: 150)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    HorizontalPickerPreview()
}


This is my code.
I was came to chatgpt also. But I can't succeed. What I do?

That seems like an usual user experience you're aiming for. Can you elaborate on your goal? (This might be an XY problem.)

Run my code in your device and check this picker. You can feel that the last selected item at the end of scrolling is not pull into the center. I want to pull it into the center as a normal number picker. Is this enough for understanding.

Yes, that helps - what you are describing is sometimes called a "tumbler UI", common for the datepicker on iOS.

Can use combine to observe midX value change and autoScroll
import Combine

In HorizontalPicker, add isScrolling property
let isScrolling = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

In .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .global).midX), add isScrolling.send() at last
.onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .global).midX) {
   ...
   isScrolling.send()
}

Whenever the midX changes this will emit an output which is void, observe this using .onReceive and using debounce you can delay autoscroll timing
.onReceive(isScrolling.debounce(for: 0.2, scheduler: RunLoop.main), perform: { _ in
    withAnimation {
       scrollView.scrollTo(selectedValue, anchor: .center)
    }
})

One issue is when user taps the value, the midX changes so the scrollView.scrollTo(selectedValue, anchor: .center) will be called again after the scroll stops in onReceive function.

Thanks a lot for my help. It i exactly work that I want. I can't vote your answer because my rank is very low. That is why, I can't vote.

@AbdulRehman Not true. You can accept the answer (click the checkmark so it becomes filled in with green color). This marks your question as answered. Do not leave the question hanging open if you regard it as successfully answered.
